# Cannot add Google Play split libraries

Tags: android, google-play

I followed the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split but I got the error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
>     You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>     However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

I tried looking around here but most of them is because they have another library that already has google-play-services but I believe it is not my case. This is my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 21
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layout/activity',
                            'src/main/res/layout/adapter',
                            'src/main/res/layout/fragment',
                            'src/main/res/layout/custom',
                            'src/main/res',
                            'src/main/rescamera',
                            'src/main/res_swipecards'
                    ]
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/libs')
    compile files('src/libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.79.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile project(':PullToRefreshLibrary')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':simpleFacebook')
    compile project(':AndroidTouchGallery')
    compile project(':camera')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.0.2'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.6'
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.playhaven.android:playhaven-api:2.2.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Do you have any Play Services JARs in `src/libs/`, where you are pulling in bare JARs from? Do any of the library modules (e.g., `camera`) that you are pulling in reference Play Services?

Comment: Thank you, I will check that now, but if that's the case then even if I use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0 it should fire the error also, right? At the moment I am using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0', still I want to use split libraries because as  you can see, I am using multipledex already and I don't think it is a good practice to do so.

Comment: "even if I use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0 it should fire the error also, right?" -- I would expect so, yes. If you are saying that you are *not* getting that error when using the `play-services` artifact, but you are getting the error when using those three individual artifacts... that I can't explain. Running a Gradle dependency report might help you determine where the conflict lies.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, I tried comment out external libraries one by one and seems like it is caused by ('com.playhaven.android:playhaven-api:2.2.6@aar'). I tried to exclude  exclude group: 'com.google.android' but no luck yet. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion about Play services used by other libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the Playhaven API 2.2.6 POM](https://nexus.playhaven.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/playhaven/android/playhaven-api/2.2.6/playhaven-api-2.2.6.pom), try excluding `com.google.android.gms`, not `com.google.android`.